# Get some sort of error indication when calling a non-existing method in Angular

Tags: angularjs, runtime-error

I just spent an hour figuring out a type. I had a component:

```
<my-component on-info-updated="vm.onInfoUpdated(info)"/>
```

Unfortunately the function in my controller was:

```
onInfoUpdate(info) { ... }
```

Update, note Updated.

Angular just swallowed this error. No warning, no nothing. Is there *any way* of getting the browser or Angular to report this?

Answer (score 0):

Angular 1 is pretty relaxed about custom attributes in the html as directive scope bindings are put together in the browser. Most browsers would render the attribute and its value as is, with no harm being caused.

With Angular 2+, the (TypeScript) compiler will normally throw an error if the template was wrongly set up like in your example.